# How to use getters and setters in PHP domain objects and transfer them correctly with Zend_Amf

Tags: apache-flex, flash, accessor, zend-amf, magic-methods

I just started to use `Zend_Amf` and thus far I'm really happy with it for sending objects from Flash to the server.
Sending my objects from the server back to my Flash environment is causing me a slight headache. My PHP objects mostly contain private properties that have a custom getter and setter method.
How do I make `Zend_Amf` aware of these properties? When sending objects from the server back to PHP it just tries. Is there an annotation for this like `@property`?
Any help is much appreciated, for now I'll try to convert the object to an `stdClass` instance with a `$_ecplicitType` value.

Comment: The final solution for this was simply to move to `Sabre_Amf`. Using `Sabre_Amf_Typed_Object` wrapper and a simple `toArray()` method on my models. The whole seems a lot more efficient...

Comment: In retrospect, using the magic function `__isset()` might do the job...